# Как правильно сравнить объект с объектами в коллекции HashSet?

Tags: java, коллекции

hashCode и equals переопределил. Пользователь вводит с консоли логин и пароль, на основании которых создается объект User и этот объект сравнивается с объектами, которые находятся в HashSet, после чего выводится сообщение в консоль. Также интересует такой вопрос, как правильно переопределять метод equals?

```
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    User user1 = new User("mike", "112233");
    User user2 = new User("jim", "223344");
    User user3 = new User("tommy", "334455");
    User user4 = new User("veronika", "556677");
    User user5 = new User("eddy", "778899");
    Authentical authentical = new Authentical(user1, user2, user3, user4, user5);
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        String login = scan.nextLine();
        String password = scan.nextLine();
        authentical.auth(login, password);
    }
}

}



public class Authentical {
Set<User> hset = new HashSet<User>();

public Authentical(User user1, User user2, User user3, User user4, User user5){
    hset.add(user1);
    hset.add(user2);
    hset.add(user3);
    hset.add(user4);
    hset.add(user5);
    for(User u:hset){
        System.out.println(u);
    }
}
public boolean auth(String login,String password){
    User user = new User(login, password);
    Iterator<User> iterator = hset.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        if(iterator.equals(user)){
            System.out.println("Пользователь с таким логином и паролем зарегистрирован");
            return true;
        }   
    }
    System.out.println("Пользователь не найден");
    return false;
}
}



public class User {
private String login;
private String password;
private int id = 17;

public User(String login, String password){
    this.login = login;
    this.password = password;
}

@Override
public int hashCode(){
    return 37 * id + login.hashCode() + password.hashCode();    
}

//упрощенный equals
public boolean equals(User user) {
     return (this.login==user.login)&&(this.password==user.password);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Основные принципы](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) при проектировании метода `equals`:

1. Рефлексивность: для любых не-null объектов x, `x.equals(x)` должен возвращать `true`.
2. Симметричность: для любых не-null объектов x и y, `x.equals(y)` должен возвращать `true`, если и только если `y.equals(x)` возвращает `true`.
3. Транзитивность: для любых не-null объектов x, y, и z, если x.equals(y) возвращает `true` и `y.equals(z)` возвращает `true`, тогда `x.equals(z)` должен возвращать `true`.
4. Постоянство: повторный вызов метода `equals()` должен возвращать одно и тоже значение до тех пор, пока какое-либо значение свойств объекта не будет изменено. То есть, если два объекта равны, то они будут равны пока их свойства остаются неизменными.
5. Для любых не-null объектов x, `x.equals(null)` должно возвращать `false`.

В методе `equals` вы сравниваете ссылки на объекты, а не их содержимое. Также обратите внимание на сигнатуру метода `equals`. В качестве аргумента принимается объект типа `Object`. Корректно будет так:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
     if (this == obj) {
         return true;
     }

     if (obj == null) {
         return false;
     }

     if (!(obj instanceof User)) {
         return false;
     }
     User otherUser = (User) obj;

     return (login.equals(otherUser.login)) && (password.equals(otherUser.password));
}
```

Также для поиска объекта в `Set` можно использовать стандартный метод [`contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Данный пример по equals актуален для реальных проектов, или же используется что-то другое?

Comment: @Hokins если используете IDE, то там обычно есть возможность автоматически переопределить методы equals() и hashCode(), но в целом они генерируют похожую структуру, которую естественно можно использовать в реальных проектах